# ray.wait() on multiple functions with different completion time

Tags: ray

I am struggling with processing results of two tasks on completion using Ray 2.2. Below is my code.  What's wrong here?

```
task_1 = A.remote(a1,a2)
task_2 = B.remote(b1,b2)
result_ids = [task_1, task_2]
while len(result_ids):
    done_id, result_ids = ray.wait(result_ids, num_returns=1, timeout=None)
    if done_id[0] is task_1:
        print('task one completed')
    elif done_id[1] is task_2:
        print('task_2 is completed')
```

print('COMPLETED TASKS')

Exception Occurred:  'object_refs' must either be an ObjectRef or a list of ObjectRefs. error is getting due to the code.

Comment: Hi! Can you share the full code? It's hard to say what the issue is exactly because `a1`/`a2`/`b1`/`b2` are not defined.

Comment: It got resolved. There was a syntax error in ray.get() method call.

Comment: You can share the fix in an answer to help others down the road! Answering your own questions it encouraged on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer